# i want display green color after some delay but it's not return anything

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm working on a quiz app and implementing the colors of users selection i want display green color after some delay but it's not return anything shows only blank button please help me i'm stuck

this is my function

```
Color? getColor(Options options, optionKey)  {

    if(modal.controller.isTapped==true && options.isTrue==true){

        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
          return AppColor.green;
        });

    }else{
      return modal.controller.btnColor[optionKey];
    }
    return null;
 }
```

calling the function

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color**:getColor(options,optionKey),**

                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                ),
```

it's working fine Future.delayed function but when i use delayed function it's not return anything
i'm expecting the output when user tap the wrong answer after some delay show the correct answer with green background color